# Is "Men Socks" correct?

Tags: translation

Just would like to know if saying "Men Socks" is correct?

It needs to mean "socks for men". By searching on google I could see that men's socks is more used.

If you speak portuguese, I was translating "meias masculinas" to English when I got this doubt.

Comment: If you meant "man socks", then maybe, yes. "Men socks" would certainly not be it. However, "man socks" could more likely imply socks as a verb! Doesn't *masculinas* translate to *male(s)* rather than *men*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Men socks* is not correct in this context because *men* is not popularly an adjective (*men* as an adjective has a different connotation, is much rarer, and is very informal).  The adjective which should replace *men* here is *men's*, as in *men's socks*.

Comment: *Men* can function as an adjective, as can any noun. Do you not retire to your *man cave* when you go home (assuming you're male and understand *men things* like that)?

Answer (score 3):

"Men's socks" is the usual expression for socks for men. I don't think I've ever heard *men socks* as a term. Men socks would seem to be the wrong term (or a very obscure term) in British English at least. It isn't that it means something other than "socks for men", but that it isn't used at all, although if I heard someone say "men socks" I would assume they meant "men's socks".

Comment: but is it correct and have the same meaning ?

Comment: You need a possessive construction, so either "men's socks" or "socks for men".

Comment: There is a... fad? Well, something like that, in Britain for saying "Man X" to represent something only men would have/use/get, e.g. men can get man-flu', drink man drinks, have man food, etc. I think it's just a shortening of manly that may well go out of fashion.

Comment: @Matt Эллен: **manly boobs?** I think not! :)

Comment: "[Man purse](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22man%20purse%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1957,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en)" has somewhat-established usage.  (At the link, ignore older "man's purse" refs)

Comment: @FumbleFingers you make a good point. I think I've blanked moobs from my mind :D

Comment: @Matt Эллен: I firmly believe all righteous-minded people, male *or* female, should blank moobs from their minds (with any luck, this comment will self-destruct as soon as you've read it! :)